# methods to solve : $6 = x+y, 65 = x^2 + y^2$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, quadratics

what's the neatest way you can solve this :

$$
\begin{cases}
 x+y=6 \\
  x^2 + y^2 =65
\end{cases}
$$
 without direct substitution? I smell some neat trick in the air here.

Comment: Have you tried graphing the functions? You will not get exact answers, but you can get a pretty good idea of the solutions will be.

Comment: @lemniscate21 yeah, I was trying to find a trigonometric/geometric solution to this since it involved circles , no luck in that department but manthanein's method is far better than what I was trying to do. sqrt(65)cos(o) = x and sqrt(65) sin(o) = y also seems to work there are messy inverse to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$65=x^2+y^2$$
$$\Rightarrow 65=(x+y)^2-2xy$$
$$\Rightarrow 65=36-2xy$$
$$\Rightarrow 2xy=-29$$
$$(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy=65+29=94$$
$$(x-y) =\pm \sqrt {94}$$

Now solve simultaneous linear equations to get answers

**Alternatively**

$(x+y)=65$ and $xy=\frac {-29}{2}$

Hence $x , y$ are the roots of the quadratic $$2m^2-12m-29=0$$

Now solve using quadratic formula

Answer (score 3):

$$2xy=(x+y)^2-(x^2+y^2)=36-65=-29$$

So, $x,y$ are the roots of $$t^2-6t-\dfrac{29}2=0$$

Comment: exactly the kind of stuff I was looking for, thanks!